# Android Studio Not Working Properly

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

When i do create a new project on Android studio my gradle build never ends.

Here is my event log

```
Gradle sync started
Gradle sync completed
Executing tasks: [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:mockableAndroidJar]
```

But if i open a previous project or some older project it opens.

Answer (score 0):

When you are creating the fresh project then gradle setup for that fresh project is being initialised and it will take some time.

Time depends upon the processing speed of computer as well as internet bandwidth.

it also depends upon the template you have choosen for startup fresh android project.

Comment: I am  getting this problem from past 1 week. My pc config is 4gb ram and intel i3 .

Comment: now downloading the latest version of android studio

Answer (score 0):

Try rebuilding your project.. Then close your project and open it again.. Sometimes I even use task manager to kill android studio because it slows down the computer and then restart it again.

Comment: I will give it a try

Answer (score 0):

i hope you are using latest version of android studio if not than change it.
bcz this problem occurred in  1.5.1.

change your classpath to  `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'`

open your build.gradle(project level)
here you can change it.

```
 dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
       // classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
```